# The referral count under acquisition tab not showing expected results on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I made a collaboration where some blogs wrote about our website (`franciacortacircuit.com`) and linked us, so i opened Google Analytics (GA) to see how many people visited our website by clicking on those links.

In GA I clicked on Acquisition -> All traffic -> Referrals and searched for the domains that linked us and...boom!
From the biggest one (which makes 15K visitors per day) whe had 55 visitors in 2 weeks, while from the other ones only 2...

They really looked too few to me so i made another test to see if everything was working fine. I checked the visits coming from another website i manage (`www.racebooking.net`), where i put a banner linking to `franciacortacircuit.com` and from where i am sure some visits came (because for debugging and testing i clicked on that banner from different devices and locations..therefore the counter cannot be 0)

Result? 0. Zero Visits from `www.racebooking.net` even if I am sure some visits came because i made those visits for testing.

This makes me think that either i am not using GA properly or I am missing something... What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

**Additional info**

1. On GA I am monitoring `http://franciacortacircuit.com` and all visits to `www.franciacortacircuit.com` are 301 redirected to `franciacortacircuit.com`
2. On the banner i made on `racebooking.net` i am not linking to the root of `http://franciacortacircuit.com` but i am linking to a sub page.

Comment: You're not filtering out your own IP address(es) so that your visits to the website aren't reported by any chance are you?

Comment: Nope. I can say this also because when i work on the website (and open many pages per day) i see a consistent increase in pageviews.